Is Automatic Plan Correction the only Query Store feature that is in SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition but not Standard Edition?
Hunting through the documentation for what is locked behind Enterprise Edition is not easy, but I gave it a good try. My conclusion was that Automatic Plan Correction is the only feature using Query Store that is in SQL Server 2019 Enterprise Edition but not Standard Edition. Am I correct?
